# getting error python object module synsets not working

Tags: python, nltk, wordnet

here is my code:

```
from nltk import wordnet 
synonyms=wordnet.synsets("dog")
```

it returns the following error message:

`AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'synset'`

Comment: did the modified import statement fix your issue?

Comment: yes thanks for that

Comment: Awesome glad I could help, feel free to use the checkmark to accept the  answer for anyone who references this question in the future!

Answer (score 3):

Here is the correct import statement:

```
from nltk.corpus import wordnet
```

You also may need to run the following in the Python prompt:

`import nltk`

`nltk.download()`

Answer (score 0):

```
from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn

wn.synset('motorcycle.n.01').definition()
Out[120]: 'a motor vehicle with two wheels and a strong frame'

wn.synset('motorcycle.n.01').lemma_names()
Out[121]: ['motorcycle', 'bike']

wn.synsets('bike')
Out[122]: [Synset('motorcycle.n.01'), Synset('bicycle.n.01'), Synset('bicycle.v.01')]

wn.synsets('motorcar')
Out[123]: [Synset('car.n.01')]
```